# Can't compile 1.9.3 with rvm using gcc

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm

I have installed **GCC-10.7-v2.pkg** found at https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads

And I have removed Xcode completely following the GCC installer's instructions.

After restarting my computer and trying to install 1.9.3. I receive this in my make.log:

```
[~] rvm install 1.9.3                               
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/pma/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/pma/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/pma/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/pma/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/pma/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /Users/pma/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/pma/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/pma/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
[~] cat /Users/pma/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/make.log
[2012-03-06 14:36:03] make 
    CC = clang
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = clang -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=shorten-64-to-32 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.3.0 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace -install_name /Users/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib -current_version 1.9.1 -compatibility_version 1.9.1 -Wl,-unexported_symbol,_Init_* -Wl,-unexported_symbol,*_threadptr_*  -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend   
    SOLIBS = 
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling dmyversion.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling load.c
compiling proc.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
io.c:997:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:1953:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:1975:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:331:52: note: instantiated from:
#define NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr) 0
                                                   ^
io.c:2409:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:2452:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:331:52: note: instantiated from:
#define NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr) 0
                                                   ^
io.c:2491:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:2515:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:331:52: note: instantiated from:
#define NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr) 0
                                                   ^
io.c:2652:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:331:52: note: instantiated from:
#define NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr) 0
                                                   ^
io.c:2662:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:3012:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:3057:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:331:52: note: instantiated from:
#define NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr) 0
                                                   ^
io.c:3172:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:3213:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:331:52: note: instantiated from:
#define NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr) 0
                                                   ^
io.c:3417:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:330:31: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE(fptr) 0
                              ^
io.c:3437:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:331:52: note: instantiated from:
#define NEED_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_ON_READ_CHECK(fptr) 0
                                                   ^
io.c:4173:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    SET_BINARY_MODE_WITH_SEEK_CUR(fptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:333:45: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_BINARY_MODE_WITH_SEEK_CUR(fptr) 0
                                            ^
io.c:4696:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:332:64: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags) 0
                                                               ^
io.c:4743:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:332:64: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags) 0
                                                               ^
io.c:8236:2: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:332:64: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags) 0
                                                               ^
io.c:8243:6: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
            SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:332:64: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags) 0
                                                               ^
io.c:8250:3: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
                SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:332:64: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags) 0
                                                               ^
io.c:8255:3: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
                SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
io.c:332:64: note: instantiated from:
#define SET_UNIVERSAL_NEWLINE_DECORATOR_IF_ENC2(enc2, ecflags) 0
                                                               ^
22 warnings generated.
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
compiling compile.c
compiling debug.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling vm.c
compiling vm_dump.c
compiling thread.c
compiling cont.c
compiling ./enc/ascii.c
compiling ./enc/us_ascii.c
compiling ./enc/unicode.c
compiling ./enc/utf_8.c
compiling newline.c
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
compiling dmyext.c
linking miniruby
<internal:prelude>:1: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0003 p:0002 s:0006 b:0006 l:000005 d:000005 TOP    <internal:prelude>:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000c78 d:000c78 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
<internal:prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ./miniruby

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: [Starting with 1.9.3-p125 Ruby compiles just fine with LLVM/clang](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2012/02/16/ruby-1-9-3-p125-is-released/) and Xcode without the third-party GCC installer should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known bug in ruby-1.9.3-p125 and another known bug in RVM,

please upgrade RVM:

```
rvm get head # or starting form April 2012:
rvm get stable
```

fix for this was introduced after releasing RVM 1.10.3 so you need to call `rvm get stable` again.

Comment: `rvm get stable` (which gives RVM version 1.10.3) doesn't make it compile unfortunately. At the moment of this writing you really do need `head`.

Comment: thanks - I'd installed RVM from stable. After installation, rvm get head was required for the xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840 - which then allowed me to rvm install 1.9.3 fine.

Comment: @AnthonyBouch I just accepted this pull request few hours ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by setting CC in my environment to GCC-4.2.